# TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict

Tags: python, xml, excel, typeerror, openpyxl

I have created a script to extract XML values via regular expressions and then append to an Excel sheet. I then added a element tree method to grab a value by the tag name. I also want to append that value to the same XLSX sheet.

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\To\Desktop\excels.py", line 23, in <module>
    ws.append(agreement)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 763, in append
    self._invalid_row(iterable)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 768, in _invalid_row
    type(iterable))
TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>
```

This is the example `elementTree` code that I found and am testing.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'test.xml'
element_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = element_tree.getroot()
agreement = root.find(".//tag").text
#variable = int(agreement)

print (agreement)


wb = Workbook()
kevin = ["1", "2", "3"]

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append(agreement)
ws.append(kevin)


# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message and full stack trace in your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`append()`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) function on a `WorkSheet` instance receives an iterable as an argument, while you are passing in a string (`agreement` variable).

Instead, you meant something like:

```
ws.append([42, agreement])
```

or:

```
ws.append([agreement])
```

Comment: That did it! Gracias!

Comment: So now say that I want to run that on a folder of XML files?

Comment: @Kevin let's close this topic and accept the provided answer. If you have additional issues, consider creating a separate question. Thanks.